# Ask permission for read SMS in react native with expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, permissions, expo

I am new to react native. My motive is asking permission to user for reading SMS in react native expo (Android & IOS). I searched in the documentation, but there is no example for this.

Comment: Apps cannot read messages on ios.  It is a privacy restriction

Comment: Tell me how to do it on Android
@Paulw11

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Comment: On the other side, I'm working on building this library for expo... let's hope for the best ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this while trying to figure this out: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3203#issuecomment-461048443

Basically, expo has removed SMS permission altogether gtom SDK 32 onwards.

**Edit (a new solution):**

I have written a library to handle this and support in expo.

You can find it on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@maniac-tech/react-native-expo-read-sms

It still needs some work, but the core part is functional